# Build Errors on upgrading from Xcode 7.2 to 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift2, xcode7

Apart from a bunch of warnings due to deprecations in Swift 2.2, I'm getting some inexplicable build errors on upgrading to Xcode 7.3 - most of them to do with interoperability between Objective-C and Swift code:

1. 'ModuleName-Swift.h' file not found
2. Extern variables defined in Objective-C files (and imported in the Bridging Header file) are not found in Swift

I've gone through the release notes and 'what's new' of Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2, and I don't find anything relevant.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out the Bridging Header path in your build settings.

Comment: I haven't seen what you explained while moving from Xcode 7.2 to 7.3, but in general those errors are 1. When you have other errors Xcode could not generate `ModuleName-Swift.h`file and so it could not be found. So, probably, you have to start with issue #2. What do you have in bridging header?

Comment: The bridging header path is correct. My point here is that the code compiles perfectly in Xcode 7.2 but not in 7.3. 
The bridging header file has a sizeable number of Objective-C header files (some of them do fail compilation because the ModuleName-Swift.h is not found).

Comment: Clear project and run it

Comment: I've done all the basic stuff like clearing derived data, cleaning the project etc.

Comment: What module name do you have in target `Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product module name`? Is it the same as `ModuleName` in `import "ModuleName-Swift.h"` statement?

Comment: Yep, the product module name is exactly the same.

Comment: The issue is now fixed. Please check my own answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was that Xcode 7.3 has introduced some structural changes to Objective-C along with Swift 2.2.

The compilation was failing because Objective-C `enum` definitions and `extern` variables had to be declared **outside** of the `@interface ... @end` block to be accessible to Swift.

The moment I moved the extern variables and enums, all my build issues were resolved.

Hope this helps others in a similar situation.